# NullPointerException on synchronized statement

Tags: java

I tried to synchronize on an object in my code below:

```
public void myMethod() {
    synchronized (globalObj) {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

The code is executed in one thread. The issue is that, another thread may set 'globalObj' to null. Then, 'synchronized (globalObj)' will throw NullPointerxception when 'globalObj' has been set to null by other threads.

What's the best practice to synchronize on an object so NullPointerException will not be thrown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should not be synchronizing on a reference that itself may be changed. If another thread is allowed to replace `globalObj`, that means you might hold a lock to the old `globalObj` while another thread works on an entirely different one - the lock doesn't help you at all.

What you should do instead is have a separate `Object` for this purpose:

```
static final Object lockObj = new Object();

public void myMethod() {
  synchronized (lockObj) {
    // do something with globalObj here
  }
}
```

Since `lockObj` never changes, you'll always use the same lock - no problems.

Answer (score 6):

You can't synchronize on a `null` reference. The best practice is to synchronize on a `final` object (to ensure that it's never `null`), or (better still) use the higher level concurrency abstractions in the `java.util.concurrent` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you synchronize on an object that cannot be null...

Why are you setting the `globalObj` to null? What should be the concurrency semantics for this? Is it by accident?

If the necessity to lock goes away sometimes (seems weird, though), you can add a null check (of course, you would need to synchronize on something else to avoid a race condition of first checking for null, and then having it set to null immediately afterwards).

Please describe your scenario in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Create a private object class member which does not have any public setters and lock on that.