# Opening xml file in two instances concurrently

Tags: multiple-instances

I have an xml file and my console app uses this file to convert it into Filestream using the code block:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(configFile, FileMode.Open)
```

But, when two instances/threads access above file on same instant/concurrently than it throws an exception which says as "Null reference exception". Can someone please help me how can it be done, as I am struggling from a longer time to go out of it...

Comment: First I think that your question is for java and is not completed because you do not see what exception occurs. I think that you be careful to synchronize resources. For this reason try to read carefully the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433493/nullpointerexception-on-synchronized-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved my problem when I have used FileAccess.Read while converting it in FileStream

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(configFile, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
```