# getting NullPointerException when using syncrhonized on null object

Tags: java

I have seen this [NullPointerException on synchronized statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433493/nullpointerexception-on-synchronized-statement).

*code*:

```
synchronized(a){
    a = new A()
}
```

So  according to the above answer *I have understood that it is not possible to use synchronized keyword on null reference*.

So I changed my code to this:

```
synchronized(a = new A()){}
```

But am not sure if this is identical with my original code?

***update:***

what I want to achieve is lock the creation of `a` (  `a = new A()` )

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I would say it's a bad idea, as each time you hit the `synchronized` block, you're creating another instance of `A`, so nothing is blocking on it.  The "lock" object needs to be shared between the threads.  May using a `static final Object` as a common monitor lock would be a better idea

Comment: There is no _null object_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`synchronized(a = new A()){}`

> so what it will do is it will create a new object of class A and use
>   that as Lock, so in simple word every thread can enter in synchronized
>   block anytime because each thread will have new lock and there will be
>   no other thread that is using that object as lock so every thread can
>   enter your synchronized block anytime and outcome will be  no
>   synchronization

**For Example**

```
class TestClass {
    SomeClass someVariable;

    public void myMethod () {
        synchronized (someVariable) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public void myOtherMethod() {
        synchronized (someVariable) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

> here we can say Then those two blocks will be protected by execution
>   of 2 different threads at any time while someVariable is not modified.
>   Basically, it's said that those two blocks are synchronized against
>   the variable someVariable.
>   **But in your case there will be always a new object so there will be no synchronization**

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized requires an object that will provide locking mechanism. It can be any object (in fact, synchronized without parameters will synchronize on **this**), but Java API provides classes dedicated to this functionality, for example [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

In code you provided every call to function containing synchronized block will use different object for locking, effectivly making synchronization useless.

Edit:
Since you updated your post with what you are actually trying to accomplish I can help you more.

```
public class Creator {
    private A a;

    public void createA() {
        synchronized(this) {
            a = new A();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this fits your design since the code sample you provided is very small, but you should get the idea. Here instance of the Creator class is used to synchronize the creation of A. If you share it across multiple threads, each one of them calling createA(), you can be sure that one instantiation process will be finished before another one begins.

Answer (score 0):

These two code snippets are not equivalent!

In the first code snippet you synchronize on some object referenced by `a`, and afterwards you change the reference which will not change the synchronization object.

In the second snippet you first assign a newly created object to reference `a` and then synchronize on it. So the synchronization object will be the new one.

Generally, it is a very bad idea to change the reference which is used in the synchronized statement, regardless whether it is done inside the block (first code) or diretcly in the synchronized statement (second code). **Make it final!** Oh, and it mustn't be `null`, either.